# How to get multiple selected row data in alert using Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Have small requirement, have to select multiple rows in a table and once we click on a button we have to show in alert all selected row data.
I tried below code, could you please help me on this.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
} );

$('#button').click( function () {
     var rowdata = table.row('.selected').data();
      for (var i = 0; i < rowdata.length; i++) {
        alert(rowdata[i]);
    }
} );
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abhbs4x8/2725/)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly, but if I did, you may just `alert(rowdata.join(" :: "))` without needing that loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you looking for is this, let me know if it doesn´t give the result you need.

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable();

        $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        } );

        $('#button').click( function () {
             var rowdata = table.rows('.selected').data();     
         var msg = '';
              for (var i = 0; i < rowdata.length; i++) {
                msg += rowdata[i]
            }
        alert(msg);
        } );
```

Just gotta replace

```
var rowdata = table.row('.selected').data();
```

for

```
var rowdata = table.rows('.selected').data();
```

to get all the rows of the table and concat all the data into a var to display it